# address of a pointer variable

Tags: c++, c

I'm currently learning c language, and I bumped into this code. ptr is already a pointer type of variable, so what is the effect of the `&` operator on it, cause I know that usually the operator uses to get the address of non-pointer variable.

```
struct name {
  int a; float b; char c[30];
};
int main()
{
  struct name *ptr;
  int i,n;
  printf("Enter n: ");
  scanf("%d",&n);
  ptr = (struct name*)malloc(n*sizeof(struct name));
  /* Above statement allocates the memory for n structures with pointer ptr pointing to       base address */ 
  for(i=0; i<n; ++i) { 
    printf("Enter string, integer and floating number respectively:\n");
    scanf("%s%d%f", &(ptr+i)->c, &(ptr+i)->a, &(ptr+i)->b); 
  }
}
```

Comment: @P0W:  Coding style and bad habits aside, this appears to be perfectly valid C++.

Comment: @JohnDibling I occasionally manage to compile C methods from questions without modification with Java, but that doesn't mean those questions should be tagged with both Java and C. In a similar way, a question shouldn't be tagged with both C and C++. A C++ tag often leads to C++-specific recommendations, which just won't help OP.

Comment: @Dukeling:  Perhaps, but the OP tagged it with both languages for a reason.  Maybe not a good reason, but a reason.  Aside from the mention of "c" in the OP, there is nothing here that suggests that the language in question cannot be C++.  The asker needs to clarify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
&(ptr + i)->c
```

this takes the address of the variable c stored at the ith element of ptr. So your first intuition was correct.

```
ptr+i
```

is simply the pointer arithmatic to find the ith element fo the array.

```
(ptr+i)->c
```

accesses the field `c` from that struct, and the `&` takes the address of that variable.

Comment: when I trying to access a member in that list through a poinetr to structure its throw me the exception "[Error] requested for the member 'info/next' im something not a sructure or a union"void struct Node_rec{
 int info;
 struct Node_rec* next;
 struct Node_rec* prev;
};
typedef struct Node_rec Node;
struct List_rec{
 Node* last;
 Node* first;
 int len;
 int sum;
};
typedef struct List_rec List;
void make_list(List l1,int new_info)
{
 Node* node=(Node*)(malloc(sizeof(Node*)));
 node.info=new_info; node.next=NULL; node.prev=NULL;
 l1.first=node;
 l1.last=node;
 l1.len=1;
 l1.sum=new_info; 
}

Answer (score 2):

The code `&(ptr + i)->c` gives you the address of the struct element `c` that belongs to the ith struct in your list. Let's break it down a bit.

`(ptr + i)` is pointer arithmetic. It adds i to the address stored at `ptr`.

`(ptr + i)->c` accesses the struct element c through the pointer `(ptr + i)`.

`&(ptr + i)->c` takes the address of the struct element c through the pointer `(ptr + i)`.

Also, I know this isn't quite doing what you thought it was doing, since you thought the address-of operator applied to the pointer, but just an FYI: you can indeed take the address of a pointer. Such a construct is a pointer to a pointer, and is useful when you want to change the pointer (not just the value stored at the address it points to) in a function. e.g.

```
int a = 5; /* regular variable */
int* pa = &a; /* pointer to a */
int** ppa = &pa; /* pointer to pointer (which points to a) */
```

Comment: Thanks, I reworded it a bit. Probably more clear now.

Comment: Definitely better. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, operator `&` in C and C++ languages is used to get address of *any* variable. More precisely, it can be used to get address of [almost] any *lvalue* (there are some differences between C and C++ in that regard). Pointer variables are ordinary variables. There's nothing special about them, which means that there's nothing unusual in seeing operator `&` applied to pointers.

Secondly, in the code you provided, there actually isn't a single instance of `&` being applied to a pointer. There are four applications of `&` in your code

```
&n
&(ptr+i)->a
&(ptr+i)->b
&(ptr+i)->c
```

In the first two cases it is applied to `int` objects. In the thirds case it is applied to `float` object. In that last case it is applied to a `char [30]` object. No pointers.

Answer (score 0):

```
struct name* ptr;
```

This creates a pointer to a `name`.

```
struct name** p = &ptr;
```

This creates a pointer to a pointer to a `name` by taking the address of the pointer you already created.

In your case, you are passing in pointers to `scanf`, and have a dynamic array of `name`, so

```
&(ptr + i)->c
```

finds the ith element of the array, and returns the address of its `c` member to `scanf` (same with `a` and `b`).

Passing in the address of the pointer allows for that pointer to be changed (e.g. reallocated).  In C++, it would be virtually identical to passing by reference.